# Trying to loop over SimpleLazyObject in template throws an error

Tags: python, django, lazy-evaluation

I have created a template context processor to query the database on every page for any global notifications. I'm using `SimpleLazyObject` to provide the results to the template, which is necessary since the function in question ultimately depends on another `SimpleLazyObject` from a different template context processor. Here's the function:

```
def company_notifications(request):
    def get_notifications():
        from app.services.companies import CompanyNotificationService
        notifications = CompanyNotificationService().company_notifications(request.profile.company)
        return notifications

    return {
        'notifications': SimpleLazyObject(get_notifications),
    }
```

When I try looping over the `notifications` variable in a template (i.e. `for notification in notifications`), I get the following error:

> TypeError at /staff/notifications object of type 'SimpleLazyObject'
>   has no len()

If instead I simply try printing the variable to the template using `{{ notifications }}`, I get what I would expect:

```
[<CompanyNotification: 57>, <CompanyNotification: 55>, <CompanyNotification: 59>]
```

But If I try instead to print a property of one of those objects, i.e. `{{ notifications[0].headline }}` I get a new error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /staff/notifications
>   Could not parse the remainder: '[0].headline' from 'notifications[0].headline'

How can I access this variable in my template?

Comment: Are you using an older version of Django? It sounds like you might be hitting [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21840), which was fixed in Django 1.7.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. By the way, the second thing you tried, `{{ notifications[0].headline }}`, isn't valid Django template code. It should be `{{ notifications.0.headline }}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alasdair's comment was right on. It's a bug in Django < 1.7. My hacky solution was to subclass SimpleLazyObject:

```
class SimpleLazyObjectFix(SimpleLazyObject):
    def __len__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 1
```